# how to conditionally render inline styles based on props

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the inline style based on props. If there is a prop use this style otherwise use something else

```
<div
  {props.bannerImg ? style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.bannerImg})` }} : style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue'}} }
  className={styles.main_header}
>
{ /*Other divs etc. here */ }
</div>
```

I however get a syntax error `Unexpected token, expected "..."`

Comment: can you please put a clear description of the error ?

Comment: @tedd, that is the only error message I get. `Unexpected token, expected "..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code to this:

```
<div
  style={
    props.bannerImg
      ? { backgroundImage: `url(${props.bannerImg})` }
      : { backgroundColor: "blue" }
  }
  className={styles.main_header}
>
  Other divs etc. here
</div>;
```

Comment: Aha! That makes more sense actually.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    <div
      style={
        props.bannerImg
          ? { backgroundImage: `url(${props.bannerImg})` }
          : { backgroundColor: "blue" }
      }
    >
      <h1>Other divs</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [Taghi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65455424/12210002) answer .

Or instead determining the style at the rendering time, you can pre-determine the style and apply that to the div which in-turn will make your jsx code cleaner .

```
export default function App(props) {

  let myStyle = { backgroundColor: 'blue'}
  
  if (props.bannerImg) 
    myStyle.backgroundColor = "red" // You can use your image path 

  return (
    <div
      style={myStyle}
      // className={styles.main_header}
    >
      hiii
     {/* demo text */}
   </div>
  );
}
```